# PHP Facade Pattern

Tags: php

I tried to learn Facade pattern, but got stuck with a problem. PHP doesnt output $totalprice from PrintPrice method. Also, here is additional information: var_dump after initializing and object gives me:

```
private 'SkiRent' => 
object(SkiRent)[2]
private 'SkiResortTicketSystem' => 
object(SkiResortTicketSystem)[3]
private 'HotelBookingSystem' => 
object(HotelBookingSystem)[4]
private 'totalprice' => null
```

but var_dump after calling HaveGoodRest gives me blank page.
I wonder if you could help me, here is the code:

```
<?php
class SkiRent
{
public function RentBoots($feetSize, $skierLevel)
{
    return 20*$skierLevel*100/$feetSize;
}
public function RentSki($weight, $skierLevel)
{
    return 40*$skierLevel*100/$weight;
}
public function RentPole($height)
{
    return 5*$height/100;
}
};

class SkiResortTicketSystem
{
public function BuyOneDayTicket()
{
    return 115;
}
public function BuyHalfDayTicket()
{
    return 60;
}
};

class HotelBookingSystem
{
public function BookRoom($roomQuality)
{
    switch ($roomQuality)
    {
        case 3:
            return 250;
        case 4:
            return 500;
        case 5:
            return 900;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException("roomQuality should be in [3;5]");       
    }

    }
};

class SkiResortFacade
{
private $SkiRent;
private $SkiResortTicketSystem;
private $HotelBookingSystem;
private $totalprice;

function __construct()
{
  $this->SkiRent = new SkiRent(); 
  $this->SkiResortTicketSystem = new SkiResortTicketSystem();
  $this->HotelBookingSystem  = new HotelBookingSystem();
}

function HaveGoodRest($height, $weight, $feetSize, $skierLevel, $roomQuality)
{
    $skiPrice = $SkiRent->RentSki($weight, $skierLevel);
    var_dump($skiPrice);
    $skiBootsPrice = $SkiRent->RentBoots($feetSize,$skierLevel);
    $polePrice = $SkiRent->RentPole($height);
    $oneDayTicketPr = $SkiResortTicketSystem->BuyOneDayTicket();
    $hotelPrice = $HotelBookingSystem->BookRoom($roomQuality);

    $this->totalprice = $skiPrice + $skiBootsPrice + $polePrice + $oneDayTicketPr + $hotelPrice;
}

public function HaveRestWithOwnSkis($roomQuality)
{
    $oneDayTicketPr = $SkiResortTicketSystem->BuyOneDayTicket();
    $hotelPrice = $HotelBookingSystem->BookRoom($roomQuality);
    return $oneDayTicketPr + $hotelPrice;
}

public function PrintPrice()
{
    echo $this->totalprice;
}

};

$rest = new SkiResortFacade();
var_dump($rest);
$height = 181.5;
$weight = 70.1;
$feetSize = 45.2;
$skierLevel = 1.2;
$roomQuality = 3;
$rest->HaveGoodRest($height, $weight, $feetSize, $skierLevel, $roomQuality);
var_dump($rest);
$rest->PrintPrice();
?>
```

Comment: Please restructure your question or it will be closed, it is not really a question or it isn't clear what you are asking...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined $this->SkiRent attribute in SkiResortFacade class:

```
$this->SkiRent = new SkiRent();
```

but you have referenced it without $this:

```
$skiPrice = $SkiRent->RentSki($weight, $skierLevel);
```

it should be:

```
$skiPrice = $this->SkiRent->RentSki($weight, $skierLevel);
```

This is a working code, so you can compare woth your version:

```
<?php
class SkiRent
{
public function RentBoots($feetSize, $skierLevel)
{
    return 20*$skierLevel*100/$feetSize;
}
public function RentSki($weight, $skierLevel)
{
    return 40*$skierLevel*100/$weight;
}
public function RentPole($height)
{
    return 5*$height/100;
}
};

class SkiResortTicketSystem
{
public function BuyOneDayTicket()
{
    return 115;
}
public function BuyHalfDayTicket()
{
    return 60;
}
};

class HotelBookingSystem
{
public function BookRoom($roomQuality)
{
    switch ($roomQuality)
    {
        case 3:
            return 250;
        case 4:
            return 500;
        case 5:
            return 900;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException("roomQuality should be in [3;5]");       
    }

    }
};

class SkiResortFacade
{
private $SkiRent;
private $SkiResortTicketSystem;
private $HotelBookingSystem;
private $totalprice;

function __construct()
{
  $this->SkiRent = new SkiRent(); 
  $this->SkiResortTicketSystem = new SkiResortTicketSystem();
  $this->HotelBookingSystem  = new HotelBookingSystem();
}

function HaveGoodRest($height, $weight, $feetSize, $skierLevel, $roomQuality)
{
    $skiPrice = $this->SkiRent->RentSki($weight, $skierLevel);
    var_dump($skiPrice);
    $skiBootsPrice = $this->SkiRent->RentBoots($feetSize,$skierLevel);
    $polePrice = $this->SkiRent->RentPole($height);
    $oneDayTicketPr = $this->SkiResortTicketSystem->BuyOneDayTicket();
    $hotelPrice = $this->HotelBookingSystem->BookRoom($roomQuality);

    $this->totalprice = $skiPrice + $skiBootsPrice + $polePrice + $oneDayTicketPr + $hotelPrice;
}

public function HaveRestWithOwnSkis($roomQuality)
{
    $oneDayTicketPr = $SkiResortTicketSystem->BuyOneDayTicket();
    $hotelPrice = $HotelBookingSystem->BookRoom($roomQuality);
    return $oneDayTicketPr + $hotelPrice;
}

public function PrintPrice()
{
    echo $this->totalprice;
}

};

$rest = new SkiResortFacade();
$height = 181.5;
$weight = 70.1;
$feetSize = 45.2;
$skierLevel = 1.2;
$roomQuality = 3;
$rest->HaveGoodRest($height, $weight, $feetSize, $skierLevel, $roomQuality);
$rest->PrintPrice();
```

Answer (score 2):

Fatal error: Call to a member function RentSki() on a non-object on line 65

```
$skiPrice = $SkiRent->RentSki($weight, $skierLevel); // Line 65
```

`$SkiRent` isn't an object because you haven't instantiated it or passed it in as an argument in the `HaveGoodRest()` method

You have multiple calls to non-objects being acted on in your code.

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped. Sorry for such a dumb question.